# How do researchers handle hypotheses?

Tags: publications

In my field (biology), the end of the introduction in a research article generally ends with a list of hypotheses that the researchers tested. A common structure of this part of a research paper is:

```
 'We tested (1) hypothesis X (2) hypothesis Y and (3) hypothesis Z'.
```

The research papers I read often test between two and four hypotheses. I'm interested in how the researchers generally arrive at this list of two and four hypotheses. Do they start with a list of 10+ hypotheses, and tick off the ones that they fail to say anything useful about? Or do they stick with the same two to four hypotheses throughout a research project? Or do researchers not begin with any hypotheses, and fit some suitable hypotheses after checking their results?

Comment: What is your hypothesis?

Comment: In a typical math paper, the hypotheses at the end of the introduction are called theorems at the end of the paper after rigorous testing. How to pick them depends on a large number of factors, and it's a skill you first learn at grad school and then keep honing as you get better at math. I'm guessing it's more or less the same in biology.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment.  In a typical math paper, there are no hypotheses, only theorems, and they are not tested, but proved.  Typically the theorems in the paper are chosen by painting the target around the arrow after it lands.

Comment: @JeffE It's not a serious comment if you didn't notice. But I do believe that what authors claim is a theorem should be understood as a hypothesis (or conjecture) until you read the proof and convince yourself or come up with your own. The editorial "we" haven't proved them; "we" are going to prove them. Hence, they're hypotheses or conjectures when you first see them in the first section. To prove is to test the validity in a specific way. Thus, it is still testing. I agree with your second point, and I think it's the same as in other fields. I don't think it contradicts my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that in many fields of study, the hypothesis is "implicit," in the sense that we're not explicitly writing down a statement such as "we believe that effect Y is the result of cause X." This is especially true in fields associated with "inverse" methods, where the idea is to build a model that explains a result. In such cases, you know what the "answer" is (the phenomenon you're looking to explain or quantify), but you might not necessarily predict in advance what causes the result you want. Even if the model is successful in reproducing the result, you may not be able to predict *why* that model worked without deeper investigation of the data that is produced. Hence, any attempt at formal, explicit hypotheses is largely guesswork.

Answer (score 3):

In my field, Physics, I have only focussed on a single, yet detailed, hypothesis.  This has been true for my thesis and published papers.

I find that it has been and is easier for me to concentrate and explore one single hypothesis thoroughly, any new hypotheses that arise from from this form the basis of several sie projects and further research.

Answer (score 3):

In social science, there are often a number of formalized hypothesis in every paper. This is because in human behavior study, there are often a number of nuances which are being studied at the same time (which allows you to reach aforementioned hypothesis)

The way in which I, as a current graduate student (not in social science but intersecting with it in my work) have been trained is through the following two approaches.

1. If I am doing qualitative research then I often adopt a [grounded theory approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Discovery_of_Grounded_Theory) in which there are no pre-determined hypotheses. There could be research questions instead.
2. If I am engaged in quantitative inquiry then I adopt formalized hypothesis from the existing literature. e.g. existing literature says X contributes to Y. I think Z is another variable which might contribute to Y ergo, I might develop H1: X + Z contributes to Y.

Answer (score 3):

In (cognitive) neuroscience, most often there is either a single hypothesis in the introduction, or two competing ones. The Journal of Neuroscience, for example, limits introductions to 500 words, which doesn't allow for much space to describe the theory behind many hypotheses.

In the results and discussion section, however, it is common to offer alternative hypotheses which could explain the obtained pattern of results, and to then proceed to discard them through control experiments, additional analyses, or on theoretical grounds. There is no real limit on the number of alternative hypotheses tested, but usually, the stronger the journal, the more analyses you need to persuade the reviewers that your explanation is the most likely one.